# Machine Learning - SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, supervised-learning

If one trains a model using a SVM from kernel data, the resultant trained model contains support vectors. Now consider the case of training a new model using the old data already present plus a small amount of new data as well. 
SO:

1. Should the new data just be combined with the support vectors from the previously formed model to form the new training set. (If yes, then how to combine the support vectors with new graph data? I am working on `libsvm`)

Or:

2. Should the new data and the complete old data be combined together and form the new training set and not just the support vectors?

Which approach is better for retraining, more doable and efficient in terms of accuracy and memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must always retrain considering the entire, newly concatenated, training set.
The support vectors from the "old" model might not be support vectors anymore in case some "new points" are closest to the decision boundary. Behind the SVM there is an optimization problem that must be solved, keep that in mind. With a given training set, you find the optimal solution (i.e. support vectors) for that training set. As soon as the dataset changes, such solution might not be optimal anymore.
The SVM training is nothing more than a maximization problem where the geometrical and functional margins are the objective function. Is like maximizing a given function *f(x)*...but then you change *f(x)*: by adding/removing points from the training set you have a better/worst understanding of the decision boundary since such decision boundary is known via sampling where the samples are indeed the patterns from your training set.
I understand your concerned about time and memory efficiency, but that's a common problem: indeed training the SVMs for the so-called *big data* is still an open research topic (there are some hints regarding backpropagation training) because such optimization problem (and the heuristic regarding which Lagrange Multipliers should be pairwise optimized) are not easy to parallelize/distribute on several workers.

LibSVM uses the well-known Sequential Minimal Optimization algorithm for training the SVM: [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.4376) you can find John Pratt's article regarding the SMO algorithm, if you need further information regarding the optimization problem behind the SVM.

Comment: So you would suggest retraining with the whole data and disregard memory efficiency if I want to focus on accuracy of the result?

Comment: 100% yes. I am working with SVMs just right now (in LibSVM and Matlab) and I really understand your concern, but that's just a sprint for writing better codes ;)

Comment: Thanks, it was extremely helpful! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Idea 1 has been already examined & assessed by research community

anyone interested in faster and smarter aproach (1) -- re-use support-vectors and add new data -- kindly review research materials published by Dave MUSICANT and Olvi MANGASARIAN on such their method referred as **`"Active Support Vector Machine"`**

> **MATLAB** implementation: available from http://research.cs.wisc.edu/dmi/asvm/
>   
> **PDF:**
> [1] O. L. Mangasarian, David R. Musicant; **`Active Support Vector Machine Classification`;** 1999
>   
> [2] David R. Musicant, Alexander Feinberg; **`Active Set Support Vector Regression`**; IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON NEURAL NETWORKS, VOL. 15, NO. 2, MARCH 2004

Comment: This only works for linear SVMs anyways. Also it doesn't seem to allow adding new data points and reusing the SVs: even the Matlab implementation should take into account previous SVMs model but the input parameters are only the data matrix and the label matrix. The Authors simply stated a more efficient way of dealing with linear SVMs. From the paper "We note that an *active set* computational strategy bears no relation to *active learning*."

Comment: Insightful paper, but would it accommodate retraining?

Comment: If I remember well, this was dealt with, as a non-terminating processing proposed in their approach in paper Dave Musicant, Olvi Mangasarian; Massive SVR via Row and Column Chunking (nips99.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is a purely theoretical thought on your question. The idea is not bad. However, it needs to be extended a bit. I'm looking here purely at the goal  to sparsen the training data from the first batch.

The main problem -- which is why this is purely theoretical -- is that your data is typically not linear separable. Then the misclassified points are very important. And they will spoil what I write below. Furthermore the idea requires a linear kernel. However, it might be possible to generalise to other kernels

To understand the problem with your approach lets look at the following support vectors `(x,y,class)`: `(-1,1,+),(-1,-1,+),(1,0,-)`. The hyperplane is the a vertical line going trough zero. If you would have in your next batch the point `(-1,-1.1,-)` the max margin hyperplane would tilt. This could now be exploited for sparsening. You calculate the - so to say - minimal margin hyperplane between the two pairs (`{(-1,1,+),(1,0,-)}`, `{(-1,-1,+),(1,0,-)}`) of support vectors (in 2d only 2 pairs. higher dimensions or non-linear kernel  might be more). This is basically the line going through these points. Afterwards you classify all data points. Then you add all misclassified points in either of the models, plus the support vectors to the second batch. Thats it. The remaining points can't be relevant.

Besides the C/Nu problem mentioned above. The curse of dimensionality will obviously kill you here

An image to illustrate. Red: support vectors, batch one, Blue, non-support vector batch one. Green new point batch two.
Redline first Hyperplane, Green minimal margin hyperplane which misclassifies blue point, blue new hyperplane (it's a hand fit ;) )

[image]